# Javascript/JQuery – few questions, should be simple

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to do a bit of jquery for a landing page I'm putting up. I'm absolutely horrible at JS so bear with me.

Here's the page where I'm developing it:

http://kickstartyourbiz.info/

For the rotating numbers under the placeholder pic, I'm using the following code:

```
<script>

setInterval(function() {
  var min = 1000;
  var max = 100000;
  var number = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  $('#random_number').fadeIn(500).text(number).delay(4000).fadeOut(450);
  var newnumber = Math.round(number / .6);
  $('#wtf').fadeIn(500).text(newnumber).delay(4000).fadeOut(450);
},
5000);

</script>

<div id="random_number"></div>

<div id="wtf"></div>
```

Few problems with this:

1) the numbers don't load until five seconds, which I'm assuming is due to the interval. But how do I get the numbers to start showing/rotating as soon as the page loads?

2) when the numbers fade out, the lower "logo" section is brought up, then back down. I'm guessing this is because the `<div>` disappears when the fade out occurs, then comes back when it fades in again. What can I do to prevent this?

Lastly, I would also like to add a dollar sign to the beginning of the numbers, and, if it's simple enough, put commas in every three numbers. So it would look something like this:

$93,029 – $163,029

Thanks for any help, really appreciate it!

**EDIT:**

Okay, think I might know what the issue is, to some extent...

So when I have this function:

```
function() {
  var min = 1000;
  var max = 100000;
  var firstnumber = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  $('#random_number').text(firstnumber);
  var newnumber = Math.floor(firstnumber / .6);
  $('#wtf').text(newnumber);
}
```

and then try and call it with , nothing shows up on the page. But then when I use this code:

```
setInterval( function() {
  var min = 1000;
  var max = 100000;
  var firstnumber = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  $('#random_number').text(firstnumber);
  var newnumber = Math.floor(firstnumber / .6);
  $('#wtf').text(newnumber);
},
5000);
```

It DOES show up on the page, but only after 5 seconds.

So I'm wondering why it won't show up on the page without setInterval?

Comment: All of it, for sure, has been asked before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **The numbers don't load until five seconds**

   The reason is that, you execute the `function() {var min ... (450);}` only after `5000` milliseconds.

   Replace:

   ```
   setInterval(function() {
       var min = 1000;
       var max = 100000;
       var number = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
       $('#random_number').fadeIn(500).text(number).delay(4000).fadeOut(450);
       var newnumber = Math.round(number / .6);
       $('#wtf').fadeIn(500).text(newnumber).delay(4000).fadeOut(450);
   },
   5000);
   ```

   With:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function () {
     var min = 1000;
     var max = 100000;
     var number = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
     $('#random_number').fadeIn(500).text(number).delay(4000).fadeOut(450);
     var newnumber = Math.round(number / .6);
     $('#wtf').fadeIn(500).text(newnumber).delay(4000).fadeOut(450);

     setInterval(function() {
       var min = 1000;
       var max = 100000;
       var number = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
       $('#random_number').fadeIn(500).text(number).delay(4000).fadeOut(450);
       var newnumber = Math.round(number / .6);
       $('#wtf').fadeIn(500).text(newnumber).delay(4000).fadeOut(450);
     },
     5000);
   }
   ```
2. **What can I do to prevent this?**

   Consider using `opacity` instead of `fadeOut` as it takes away content from the DOM, which gives you the jump.
3. **I would also like to add a dollar sign to the beginning of the numbers**

   Consider using [jQuery Number Format](http://www.teamdf.com/web/jquery-number-format/178/), a jQuery plugin, which does the same thing which you expect.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the answer.

For the first one, how do I execute the function THEN go into the interval? Seems like it should be pretty damn easy, scratching my head at it though.

Comment: Put the function on a normal `function theWork() {}` and call it in the `setInterval()`, this way: `setInterval(function(){theWork();}, 5000); theWork();`, where the second `theWork()` executes it as soon as the page is loaded.

Comment: Done. You've already given me some new directions to look into, but the code is still not executing immediately. If you have a second, could you see if something's off here?
`setInterval(function() {
 theNumbers(); 
 }, 
 5000);
 
 theNumbers();`

Comment: Updated the answer. @user1727053 Please check the point #1 again.

Comment: Copy and pasted directly, still doesn't load for 5 seconds.

Comment: Dude, please show what you have copied and pasted. Update in the answer. :)

Comment: Oops, sorry about that! Updated the answer, at the bottom.

Comment: Wrap the whole of `setInterval()` and `someTime()` inside `$(document).ready(function(){ /* Here */ });`

Comment: In the `console`, what do you get? Any errors? Have you hosted this somewhere to test it out?

Comment: Okay, made a new update to the original question, might shed some light on things (look at the bold section). Thanks for helping me out man... I know I'm a complete noob at this.

Comment: Add the `function()` section + `setTimeout()` section to the `$(document).ready()`. See my updated answer.

Comment: Put in the new code, still nothing... This is getting to be too much of a hassle, I'll just ask one of my programmer friends to take a look at it later. Thanks for all your help Praveen!